# What does "to-" in today, tomorrow, tonight mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

As in the title. Does it mean anything? Does it mean the same thing in all of these words? What is its origin? Are there any other words with "to-"?

Answer (score 7):

It is a prefix that in some cases ( like today ) has survived from Middle  English usage in words with reference to time meaning *on* ( this day):

[Today:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Today&searchmode=none)

> - Old English todæge, to dæge "on (this) day," ***from to "at, on" (see to) + dæge, dative of dæg "day" (see day)***. Meaning "in modern times" is from c. 1300. As a noun from 1530s. Generally written as two words until 16c., after which it usually was written to-day until early 20c.

[To](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=to&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - Old English to "in the direction of, for the purpose of, furthermore," from West Germanic *to (cognates: Old Saxon and Old Frisian to, Dutch too, Old High German zuo, German zu "to"), from PIE pronominal base *do- "to, toward, upward" (cognates: Latin donec "as long as," Old Church Slavonic do "as far as, to," Greek suffix -de "to, toward," Old Irish do, Lithuanian da-), from demonstrative *de-.
> - ***Commonly used as a prefix in Middle English (to-hear "listen to," etc.), but few of these survive (to-do, together, and time references such as today, tonight, tomorrow -- Chaucer also has to-yeere)***. To and fro "side to side" is attested from mid-14c. Phrase what's it to you "how does that concern you?" (1819) is a modern form of an old question:

(Etymonline)

Comment: Isn't it prefix according to your source?

Comment: @RexYuan - sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The "to" is the versatile preposition, which comes to us from Old English.  It has a temporal meaning of on (a day) or in (a time).  Others?  Sure.  "Together" and "toward."  The "to" has a different meaning in locational use.

Comment: Then why "in-morrow"/"on-morrow" means what tomorrow? Doesn't make sense. Also what would "gether" be?

Comment: @NPS There’s no way of knowing why it’s _today/-morrow/night/-gether/-ward_, rather than _onday/-morrow/etc._ That’s just the preposition they decided to use in the area where what later became Old English developed. Other Germanic languages chose other prepositions to use. The Nordic languages all have ‘in’, for example, like Danish _i dag, i aften, i morgen_; but then in Icelandic it’s still _í dag, í kvöld_, but _á morgun_ ‘on morrow’, and _í morgun_ instead means ‘this morning’. And of course in English _tomorrow_ is equivalent to ***on*** _the morrow_. Prepositions vary. They just do.

Comment: And _-gether_ is a [cranberry morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme) which is historically (and still at least semi-transparently) related to the verb _gather_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, special thanks for the link to semi-transparent cranberry morphemes.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You didn't understand me. I didn't ask why this preposition and not any other. I asked why tomorrow means a time in the next day and not this one.

Comment: @NPS That's a common thing in Indo-European languages: for whatever reason, we use a word for ‘morning’ to refer to the day after today. It's the same in Romance languages where French _demain_, Spanish _mañana_, Italian _domani_, etc. ultimately all go back to variations of Latin _dē manē_ ‘in the morning’. Probably the logic is that when you speak of ‘morning’, you mean the next one that comes, and during the day, after morning has passed, the next morning that comes around also entails the next day.

Comment: I thought of that but it's possible to speak of morning before it comes (the same day). :P